# Android - Pass String from activity to library activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm currently experimenting with creating my own libraries (aar) and I've come to the point that I have a library with an activity in it up and running in my project. But I have one small problem that I can't solve: how do I send a String from my Mainactivity to the activity that I created in my library?

I know that if I was working with activities that belong to the same project I could just create an intent in activity 1, add a putExtra with the String, start the activity and dig up that intent in activity 2. But the activity in my library doesn't know the activity in my project exists, so that doesn't work.

I could put the info in my SharedPreferences, but I'd like to avoid that.

Any help? I've been searching the web and I've found a solution for the other way around, but sadly that's useless to me :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The activity in your library doesn't have to "know" the first one... It has just to check if the intent contains the extra you sent:

```
if(getIntent().getStringExtra("yourStringExtraName") != null){
//Do your stuff here
}else{
//Do stuff when there isn't your string
}
```